# Camel -Specific exception processing handling based on message

Tags: apache-camel

I have a queue system of which camel is just a small part of. In this queue system, for some queues, the broker returns FAIL when the queue is full. To handle this, I look at JMS Exception I get and from the message I can see whether or not the reason is that the queue is full.

What I want to achieve in Camel is that for the specific case of full queue, I want to retry deliveries, whereas for any other JMS Exception (or any other exception) I want to send it to DLQ.

I'm assuming that I have to use the onException(JMSException.class) and provide a custom processor which will look at the exception message, but after that, I'm not sure what to do. I tried raising a specific custom exception from the processor in that case (e.g. QueueFailedException) and have another onException(QueueFailedException) in the setup, but then I get the following error:

"(...) ERROR org.apache.camel.processor.FatalFallbackErrorHandler - Exception occurred while trying to handle previously thrown exception on exchangeId: (...) using: [Channel[DelegateSync[org.eumetsat.gems.bridge.JmsMessageReplicator$JMSExceptionHandler@67a93d5f]]]. The previous and the new exception will be logged in the following."

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, you need to tell Camel it must consider an exception handled and also it should retry sending the message according to some logic check. The `.handled()` also accepts a Predicate or an Expression besides Boolean.

Don't the following sections help you achieve that?

- [Marking exceptions as handled](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/exception-clause.html#_marking_exceptions_as_handled)
- [Using fine grained retry using retrywhile predicate](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/exception-clause.html#_using_fine_grained_retry_using_retrywhile_predicate).

I'm considering you're able to identify if the exception was really caused by a queue flooding through a caught JMSException.